# NetSuite custom field "Hidden" display type

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've seen some odd behavior when trying to use custom fields with the `hidden` display type. It appears as if admins and the system users can edit hidden fields via `SuiteScript`. However, when other users attempt to change the hidden fields' value via SuiteScript, the script doesn't error out but also doesn't make any change to the hidden field.

Is this expected behavior? Has anyone else run into this type of issue with hidden fields?

Comment: From NetSuite help documentation: "Be aware that in SuiteScript, only user event, scheduled, and Suitelet scripts can set the value of a custom field that has a display type of hidden." --- This might be the problem. I'm setting the field in a workflow action script. However, why would it allow admins and the system user to set it? Maybe it's more accurate to say ""Be aware that in SuiteScript for non-admin/system users, only user event, scheduled, and Suitelet scripts can set the value of a custom field that has a display type of hidden."

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2780140.html#:~:text=On%20the%20workflow%20definition%20page,that%20initiated%20the%20workflow%20instance.